# Login component as popup window in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

I have implemented the login component in Sitecore SXA. It is coming properly on the page. Now the customer is asking about the feasibility of the login component as a pop window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, just create an Overlay page with your Login component inside.

[image]

Then add a Link component and point it to your overlay page, don't forget to add the class "Links Shown in Overlay" to your Link component.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jorge. This is what I expected.